# Default selected value in semantic ui dropdown

Tags: javascript, html, dropdown, semantic-ui

I am trying to append options to select and with a default selected value.

Here is my **HTML** code

```
<div class="ui element" id="action-div">
    <label for="action-type">Action</label>
    <select id="action-type" class="ui dropdown" name="Action">
    </select>
</div>
```

**JavaScript code**

```
$('#action-type').append('<option value="initiate">Initiate</option>\n' +
    '<option value="generate">Generate</option>\n' +
    '<option value="cancel_and_reinitiate">Cancel and Reinitiate</option>\n' +
    '<option value="data_correction">Data Correction</option>').val('initiate');
```

I want to select the first item by default but it is not working.

Please help here.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Try with `<option value="generate" selected = "selected"> Generate<option>`. Now default value of dropdown is set to Generate.

I used *Generate* to show you how to set default value to select. If you want then you can use `selected=selected` for first element as well

```js
$('#action-type').append('<option value="initiate">Initiate</option>\n' +
        '<option value="generate" selected = "selected">Generate</option>\n' +
        '<option value="cancel_and_reinitiate">Cancel and Reinitiate</option>\n' +
        '<option value="data_correction">Data Correction</option>');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="ui element" id="action-div">
        <label for="action-type">Action</label>
        <select id="action-type" class="ui dropdown" name="Action">
        </select>
</div>
```